# below labels are misplaced

Tags: tikz-pgf

any idea why the labels placed "below" (ex: B) are misplaced, while above, left and right labels are properly placed?

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INTRODUCTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}%  permet de dessiner des figures, des graphiques
\usepackage{adjustbox}% permet de déterminer une taille de fenêtre
%%  FONT
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgadventor}% paquet de police de caractère TGadventor
\usepackage{sansmath}%  Copie-colle la police active dans 
%                       \sfdefault (/!\ N'EST PAS UNE POLICE DE CARACTÈRES)
\usepackage{xcolor}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INPUT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\input{preamble.tex}
%\input{parameters.tex}

%\input{types/f2d_figlab}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SETUP %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{
    fig2D/.style={font={\sansmath\sffamily\Large}, line width=0.4mm, line cap=round, line join=round, >=latex, x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm,},
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOTTED TRIANGLOID %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    pics/dotted triangloid/.style={code={%
    \tikzset{triangloid/.cd,#1}%
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/triangloid/##1}}
    \draw [solid, pic actions, fill=\pv{fill}]
    %%  point o - bas gauche
    (0,0) coordinate (o)
    node [circle, fill=black, scale=0.5, label={[\pv{poso}, inner sep=\pv{inner sep},]\pv{labo}}] {}
    %% point a - bas droite
    (\pv{scale}*\pv{width},0) coordinate (a)
    node [circle, fill=black, scale=0.5, label={[\pv{posa}, inner sep=\pv{inner sep},]\pv{laba}}] {}
    %% point b - sommet
    ({\pv{scale}*\pv{offset})},\pv{scale}*\pv{height}) coordinate (b)
    node [circle, fill=black, scale=0.5, label={[\pv{posb}, inner sep=\pv{inner sep},]\pv{labb}}] {}
    %% jonction entre les points
     (o) 
     -- (a) 
     node [midway, label={[\pv{posA}, inner sep=\pv{inner sep},shift={(0pt,-6pt)}]\pv{labA}}] {}
     -- (b)
     node [midway, label={[\pv{posB}, inner sep=\pv{inner sep},]\pv{labB}}] {}
     -- (o)
     node [midway, label={[\pv{posC}, inner sep=\pv{inner sep},,shift={(-2pt,0pt)}]\pv{labC}}] {}
     ;
  }},
  triangloid/.cd,
  width/.initial=5,
  height/.initial=2,
  offset/.initial=0,
  labA/.initial=,
  labB/.initial=,
  labC/.initial=,
  labo/.initial=,
  laba/.initial=,
  labb/.initial=,
  posA/.initial=below,
  posB/.initial=above right,
  posC/.initial=left,
  poso/.initial=below,
  posa/.initial=below,
  posb/.initial=above,
  inner sep/.initial=0pt,
  fill/.initial=black!0,
  scale/.initial=1,
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fig2D]

\pic {dotted triangloid={width=8.82, height=6.47, offset=2.35, labo=B, laba=C, labb=A, posa=right, inner sep=0pt, fill= orange!20}};

\path
    (o) -- (b) node [circle, pos=0.333, fill=black, scale=0.5, label=below right: D] (d) {}
    (a) -- (b) node [circle, pos=0.333, fill=black, scale=0.5, label=below left: E] (e) {}
;

\draw
    %%%     Tracé segment DE
    (d) -- (e)
    %%%     Tracé segment en pointillé
    (o) +(-3pt, 3pt) coordinate (o')
    (b) +(-5pt, -3pt) coordinate (b')
    (o') edge[<->, densely dashed,] node [left, inner sep=6pt]{12 cm} (b')
    %
    (d) +(3pt, 3pt) coordinate (d')
    (e) +(-3pt, 3pt) coordinate (e')
    (d') edge[<->, densely dashed,] node [above, inner sep=6pt]{6 cm} (e')
    %
    (o) +(3pt, -3pt) coordinate (o'')
    (a) +(-3pt, -3pt) coordinate (a')
    (o'') edge[<->, densely dashed,] node [below, inner sep=10pt]{10 cm} (a')
;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary: change

```
node [circle, fill=black, scale=0.5, label={[\pv{poso}, inner sep=\pv{inner sep},]\pv{labo}}] {}
```

to

```
node [circle, fill=black, scale=0.5, label={[inner sep=\pv{inner sep},]\pv{poso}:\pv{labo}}] {}
```

and similar for the other labels.

---

The syntax for a `label` is

```
label={[<options>]<angle>:<text>}
```

where `<angle>` defines the position of the label relative to the node to which it belongs. You have used the syntax

```
label={[<options>]<text>}
```

leaving out the `<angle>:`. As described in the manual, if the `<angle>` is missing, `above` is used, i.e. the label is placed above the node.

Your `poso` etc. are added as part of the label style, meaning that they only affect the anchor of the label node, *not its position relative to the "parent" node*. Take this simplified example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [circle, fill=black!50, label={[inner sep=0,draw=blue,ultra thin,above]B}] {};
\node [circle, fill=black!50, label={[inner sep=0,draw=blue,ultra thin,below]B}] at (0.5,0) {};
\node [circle, fill=black!50, label={[inner sep=0,draw=blue,ultra thin]below:B}] at (1,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The label on the left has `above` in its style, which is just another way of saying `anchor=south`. The one in the middle has `below`, meaning `anchor=north`. And as you can see, the `south` anchor on the left hand label is in the same place relative to the node as the `north` anchor on the middle label.

In the right hand label however, `below` is added as the `<angle>`, and hence the label is placed below the node (and with `anchor=north` as default).

Comment: thank you very much